# Convert SPFieldMultiLineText to HtmlField

Tags: sharepoint, field

Is there a way to convert a SPFieldMultiLineText to HtmlField using code?

Answer (score 1):

`SPFieldMultiLineText` is used to display text. Did you tried with `SPFieldMultiLineText.GetFieldValueAsHtml`. This Returns the field value in HTML format in order to render the value directly on the page. Find this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultilinetext.getfieldvalueashtml.aspx)